# AS3 How To Pass Frames

Tags: actionscript-3, frames

I have a small problem with my game. I want when my player reaches a box collision this calls another frame which I put an animation in it. And, when this animation ends, I wanna this frame calls another one where the second level is.

I have all the codes, collision, remove listeners to stop the actual frame functions, but when I put `gotoAndStop("animationframe");` the frame remains in loop and never goes to the second level.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to show us some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the animation dispatch a [bubbling](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/eventbubbles-eventcancelable-and-eventcurrenttarget) event at the end that you're listening for at the top level. When you hear the event, go to the other frame.

If you're a timeline person, you can do something like

```
   dispatchEvent(new Event('imDone', true);
```

If you're not, you can do something like this in the constructor of the Base Class for that animation:

```
   addFrameScript(totalFrames-1, function ():void {
      dispatchEvent(new Event('imDone', true));
   });
```

or you could add an enter frame listener and check for being on the last frame and dispatch the event if you are.